# Vale a pena 'embaralhar' ID que será passado via URL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysqli

Estávamos conversando sobre segurança em banco de dados.

Veio a questão: vale a pena criptografar IDs vindos do banco de dados para o frontend?

Ex.: clico em um cliente de uma lista onde o link vai http://localhost/get_posts/id_criptografado me retorna todos os `posts` deste.

Enfim, uma aplicação ficaria mais segura utilizando os IDs criptografados?

Comment: melhor usar `.htaccess` do que embaralhar ids.

Comment: Eu ja vi essa discussão aqui no site, só não estou lembrando o contexto para linkar. Já adianto que quase sempre não faz o mínimo sentido, e quando faz, o autor do código normalmente vê claramente a necessidade. Geralmente as "ofuscações" de ID mais geram problema do que resolvem (começa a ter que se preocupar com colisão e outras N coisas) - não confundir com usar bases diferentes para URL, como fazem o bit.ly e outros encurtadores, por exemplo. Nestes casos meramente se usa um set maior de caracteres para compactar a informação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que você tem que definir quais são suas preocupações, para então saber se vale ou não apena.

---

Existem casos e casos de uso. O YouTube é um exemplo, ele não usa identificadores sequenciais. Isso é: um vídeo será `youtube.com/1` outro será `youtube.com/821`, ao invés de `/2`.

Agora, qual motivo leva o YouTube a gerar identificadores não-sequenciais? Para prevenir que acessasse vídeos "não-listados", afinal se fossem sequencial você poderia acessar os vídeos com `/3`, `/4`, `/5` e, creio eu, para não conflitar com vários envios simultâneos...

> *PS: O YouTube, assim como o Instagram, não usa números, mas ele codifica para Base64. A codificação NÃO tem haver com a segurança, a vantagem é que tanto faz se for 1 ou 18446744073709551614, ele será representado pela mesma quantidade de caracteres e usará menos do que se usar números, já que os dois números podem ser guardados em 8 bytes.*

---

Expor o ID em geral não é um problema, o Facebook e o Instagram, expõe o ID do usuário e é sequencial também. A primeira foto do Instagram é o [`ID: 2`](https://www.instagram.com/p/C/) e o primeiro do Facebook é o [`ID: 4`](http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=4), mas isso é um problema?! Não problema em sabermos dessa informação.

> PS: Note, publicações privadas no Instagram possuem outro identificador, que é mais longo e não parece ser sequencial.

Se for, o meu conselho seria: cria um outra coluna como `id_random`, e use ele como um `id`. Não será preciso de nada relacionado à criptografia, exceto um gerador aleatório seguro, e só. Mas, se você quer que cada usuário veja um ID diferente, então derive ele usando algum KDF (um HMAC/Keyed-Hash) para uma chave especifica por usuário ou encripte usando algum algoritmo que garanta integridade (AES-GCM, ChaCha20Poly1305, Salsa20Poly1305...) ou use algum "obscurador não-criptográfico ao seu desejo", dessa forma o identificador de um usuário (ou de um "alguma coisa") vai variar dependendo de quem está conectado no momento. Agora onde isso pode ser útil? Não sei.

Answer (score 2):

Mais ou menos, se a segurança da sua aplicação consiste em esconder do usuário o que ele pode mexer, ela vai estar tão segura como agora, a diferença é que os ID vão ser "bagunçados"

Pode até ficar mais difícil encontrar outro recurso, se você estiver usando ids sequenciais, já que é só acrescentar ou decrementar para acessar o próximo ou anterior. Mas isso não dá muita segurança, um invasor pode ficar fazendo requisições em massa com ids aleatórios e acabar encontrando de qualquer forma

Se o usuário não tem permissão para acessar determinado recurso, você não deve apenas esconder, mas fazer uma validação antes de mostrar e retornar um erro